# provisioning profile problem after upgrading to snow leopard?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, osx-snow-leopard

i just upgraded my macbook OS to Snow Leopard but all the provisining profiles were deleted..Do i need to create new provisioning profiles for all applications or just copy my bACKUP OF provisioning profiles folder to the Library(havent installed xcode 3.2 iphone sdk4 yet)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install xcode 3.2 and then install all profiles.

Comment: You can also add provisional profiles by dragging them in to iTunes.